# How to convert many array to a single array

Tags: php, arrays

So i have array like this. See at pastebin link
https://pastebin.com/5T7uxmvm
I want to convert that array's to a single array

```
foreach($arrays as $array) {
        $result = call_user_func_array("array_merge", $array);
        print_r($result);
    }
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can use `array_merge` with `...` **splat operator** to merge all the sub-array of an array into a single array

```
$res = array_merge(...$arrays);
```

Live DEMO : https://3v4l.org/mWpKp

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this. I know it is not the best solution. But it works on the second array.

**Code**

```php
$arrays = array(
    array(1,2,3,4),
    array(45,634,6345,63),
    array(12,1234,1234,1234)
);

$newArr = array();

foreach($arrays as $array){
    foreach($array as $key => $value){
        $newArr[] = $value;
    }
}

echo '<pre>';
print_r($newArr);
echo '<pre>';
```

**Output**

```
Array
(
    [0] => 1
    [1] => 2
    [2] => 3
    [3] => 4
    [4] => 45
    [5] => 634
    [6] => 6345
    [7] => 63
    [8] => 12
    [9] => 1234
    [10] => 1234
    [11] => 1234
)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with a built in simple array_merge function, e-g

```
$result = [];
foreach($arrays as $array) {
    $result = array_merge($result, $array);
}
print_r($result);
```